# F# tail recursion with XAMARIN MAC OS

Tags: xamarin, f#, mono, stack-overflow, tail-recursion

I'm trying to implement this example from 
http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/recursive-types-and-folds-2/

I'm running on Xamarin 6.1.5 for MAC OS

Here is the code

```
type Book = {title: string; price: decimal}

type ChocolateType = Dark | Milk | SeventyPercent
type Chocolate = {chocType: ChocolateType ; price: decimal}

type WrappingPaperStyle = 
    | HappyBirthday
    | HappyHolidays
    | SolidColor

type Gift =
    | Book of Book
    | Chocolate of Chocolate 
    | Wrapped of Gift * WrappingPaperStyle
    | Boxed of Gift 
    | WithACard of Gift * message:string

// A Book
let wolfHall = {title="Wolf Hall"; price=20m}
// A Chocolate
let yummyChoc = {chocType=SeventyPercent; price=5m}
// A Gift
let birthdayPresent = WithACard (Wrapped (Book wolfHall, HappyBirthday), "Happy Birthday")
// A Gift
let christmasPresent = Wrapped (Boxed (Chocolate yummyChoc), HappyHolidays)

let rec cataGift fBook fChocolate fWrapped fBox fCard gift :'r =
    let recurse = cataGift fBook fChocolate fWrapped fBox fCard
    match gift with 
    | Book book -> 
        fBook book
    | Chocolate choc -> 
        fChocolate choc
    | Wrapped (gift,style) -> 
        fWrapped (recurse gift,style)
    | Boxed gift -> 
        fBox (recurse gift)
    | WithACard (gift,message) -> 
        fCard (recurse gift,message) 

let totalCostUsingCata gift =
    let fBook (book:Book) = 
        book.price
    let fChocolate (choc:Chocolate) = 
        choc.price
    let fWrapped  (innerCost,style) = 
        innerCost + 0.5m
    let fBox innerCost = 
        innerCost + 1.0m
    let fCard (innerCost,message) = 
        innerCost + 2.0m
    // call the catamorphism
    cataGift fBook fChocolate fWrapped fBox fCard gift

let deeplyNestedBox depth =
    let rec loop depth boxSoFar =
        match depth with
        | 0 -> boxSoFar 
        | n -> loop (n-1) (Boxed boxSoFar)
    loop depth (Book wolfHall)


let rec totalCostUsingAcc costSoFar gift =
    match gift with 
    | Book book -> 
        costSoFar + book.price  // final result
    | Chocolate choc -> 
        costSoFar + choc.price  // final result
    | Wrapped (innerGift,style) -> 
        let newCostSoFar = costSoFar + 0.5m
        totalCostUsingAcc newCostSoFar innerGift 
    | Boxed innerGift -> 
        let newCostSoFar = costSoFar + 1.0m
        totalCostUsingAcc newCostSoFar innerGift 
    | WithACard (innerGift,message) -> 
        let newCostSoFar = costSoFar + 2.0m
        totalCostUsingAcc newCostSoFar innerGift 


let rec foldGift fBook fChocolate fWrapped fBox fCard acc gift :'r =
    let recurse = foldGift fBook fChocolate fWrapped fBox fCard 
    match gift with 
    | Book book -> 
        let finalAcc = fBook acc book
        finalAcc     // final result
    | Chocolate choc -> 
        let finalAcc = fChocolate acc choc
        finalAcc     // final result
    | Wrapped (innerGift,style) -> 
        let newAcc = fWrapped acc style
        recurse newAcc innerGift 
    | Boxed innerGift -> 
        let newAcc = fBox acc 
        recurse newAcc innerGift 
    | WithACard (innerGift,message) -> 
        let newAcc = fCard acc message 
        recurse newAcc innerGift


let totalCostUsingFold gift =  

    let fBook costSoFar (book:Book) = 
        costSoFar + book.price
    let fChocolate costSoFar (choc:Chocolate) = 
        costSoFar + choc.price
    let fWrapped costSoFar style = 
        costSoFar + 0.5m
    let fBox costSoFar = 
        costSoFar + 1.0m
    let fCard costSoFar message = 
        costSoFar + 2.0m

    // initial accumulator
    let initialAcc = 0m

    // call the fold
    foldGift fBook fChocolate fWrapped fBox fCard initialAcc gift 


[<EntryPoint>]
let main args =

       printfn "Arguments passed to function : %A" args
       let a = deeplyNestedBox 100000

       let res2= a |> totalCostUsingFold 


       // printfn "res2 = %A" res2
       0
```

It looks to me this is tail recursive, (like said on the webpage)
but i do get a stackoverflow error at runtime

In the compile options of the project, i do have selected the box "generate tail calls"

Is there anything wrong with my code, or with Xamarin ?

Comment: It's possible that this is a limitation of Mono, if you search SO, a few Issues regarding tail call optimization will pop up. E.g. [this ticket](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=12635) is still open.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this is the reason for the stack overflow, but the recursive calls in `cataGift` do not look tail-recursive to me:

```
let rec cataGift fBook fChocolate fWrapped fBox fCard gift :'r =
    let recurse = cataGift fBook fChocolate fWrapped fBox fCard
    match gift with 
    | Book book -> 
        fBook book
    | Chocolate choc -> 
        fChocolate choc
    | Wrapped (gift,style) -> 
        fWrapped (recurse gift,style)
    | Boxed gift -> 
        fBox (recurse gift)
    | WithACard (gift,message) -> 
        fCard (recurse gift,message)
```

In the last three cases, you are calling `recurse gift` which is a recursive call and you are then passing the result to another function like `fCard` or `fBox`.

To make it tail-recursive, you'd need to change the code so that call to `recurse` is the last thing in the body of the match case (possibly using a continuation, or by passing the `fCard` function to `recurse` in some way).

Comment: catagift is not tail recursive. foldGift is. this is the function which is called in totalCostUsingFold, which is called in the main part. catagift was just there for context given i took the source from the http link. I could/should have removed from this discussion

Comment: Ah, thanks for the clarification - would it help to remove the `let recurse` definition and just directly call `foldGift`?

Comment: hi Thomas
removing `let recurse` and call directly `foldGift` indeed works !!
but thats strange, isn't the code still tail recursive with the original syntax ?

Comment: @FaguiCurtain Yes, the code is still tail-recursive, but with the inner function, it gets compiled using the `.tail` instruction. Without that, I think the compiler can optimize the code on its own.

Comment: I'm not sure i understand your comment. With the inner function, if its compiled with `.tail`, shouldn't it be good like its name is suggesting ?
i remember vaguely how to see the assembly under VS , how do i get to see it in (Mono)/Xamarin and where exactly should i look for hints of tail recursion in the assembly ?

Comment: @FaguiCurtain Yes, I think it should still work - but in case there is something wrong in mono with `.tail`, the version with local function would not work, but the one without it still would...

Comment: i guess you're using Windows ?

Answer (score 1):

Last I looked (which was years ago) Mono doesn't support tail calls so you can expect stack overflows from tail recursive functions on Mono.

Yup, Mono still doesn't support tail calls:

https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=12635#c11

That's scary!